# BuildBot not seeing SVN URL switch

Tags: svn, buildbot

We recently changed our SVN server to a secure server. Our BuildBot doggedly keeps accessing the old http:// address instead of https://, even though the master.cfg file is updated to the new URL, BuildBot and servers have been restarted, but to no avail. The SVN poller uses the new https:// address correctly, but the builds keep trying to access the old invalid url.

Can somebody please advise?

Thanks in advance,
Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

By default Buildbot updates subversion build's working directory incrementally by running `svn update`.

Your working directory was previously checked out with `http://` URL, and without [relocating](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) them or removing/re-checkouting them, `svn update` will attempt to use old URL.

My advice is to either clear build's working directory manually, or temporary [set](https://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#svn) SVN checkout `mode` to `full`, and `method` to `clobber`.

**EDIT:**

Which version of Buildbot do you use?
[Issue related to changing SVN URLs](http://trac.buildbot.net/ticket/2467) described above was fixed in at least Buildbot 0.8.9.
If your version is 0.8.9 or newer can you post parts of your `master.cfg` related to SVN for further investigation, please?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, rutsky. We have BuildBot 0.8.12 installed, but your helpful reply made me realize that our master config script is actually using an older version of BuildBot. We'll update the master.cfg file to the latest API, perhaps that solves our problem.